I want to set up database connection code-wise in Next.js version 14 project from scratch and i am using mariadb for database and tool is hedisql
Please Guide me from a structure of code to connection in code
I have not try yet, I'd be glad to guide you through setting up a database connection with MariaDB in your Next.js 14 project using Hedisql as your database management tool
